# Border thickness transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is there a way to ease-in-out between 2 border thicknesses?

My code:

```
nav a {
border-bottom: 1px solid #AADA4B;
}


nav a:hover {
border-bottom: 3px solid #AADA4B;
}
```

Thanks very much for the help.
Sam.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure, just transition `border` or `border-width` on the `a` element:

```
nav a {
/* -moz-, -o-, -webkit- prefixes omitted for brevity */
transition: border-width 0.1s ease-in-out;
border-bottom: 1px solid #AADA4B;
}
```

Comment: If the border color doesn't change, I would also suggest this on hover: `nav a:hover { border-bottom-width: 3px; }`. It's easier to maintain the code like this.